# UITextView: How to really disable editing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to disable editing on my `UITextView`. I have tried `[aboutStable setUserInteractionEnabled: NO]`, but it causes the page to not be accessible.

Here is the current code.

```
- (void)loadTextView1 {
    UITextView *textView1 = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];
    [textView1 setText:@"Example of editable UITextView"];
    [textView1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [textView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [textView1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [textView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 29, 290, 288)];
    [self addSubview:textView1];
    [textView1 release];
}
```

Comment: Any way to do this without changing my code?  Just by adding something?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First of all, you are using setter methods when you could just be using properties. Secondly, you are setting a whole bunch of unnecessary properties that are very close to the default. Here is a much simpler and perhaps what you intended with your code:

#### Objective-C

```c
- (void)loadTextView1 {
    UITextView *textView1 = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 29, 290, 288)];
    textView1.text = @"Example of non-editable UITextView";
    textView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    textView1.editable = NO;
    
    [self addSubView:textView1];
    [textView1 release];
}
```

#### Swift

```swift
func loadTextView1() {
    let textView1 = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 29, width: 290, height: 288))
    textView1.text = "Example of non-editable UITextView"
    textView1.backgroundColor = .clear

    textView1.isEditable = false

    addSubView(textView1)
}
```

Comment: No turning back now... Did that on 40 views.  Thanks though.

Comment: The key bit is the addition of `textView1.editable = NO;`. Besides, you should never have code repeated on 40 views.

Comment: You are using setter methods in your code as well.  `textView1.text` and `[textView1 setText:` are equivalent.

Comment: Inafziger: Yes, but I am using it via the shorthand property syntax.

Comment: Yes, but your answer says "First of all, you are using setter methods when you could just be using properties".

Comment: "But it's my first app" is never an excuse to avoid some simple refactoring.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using setters instead of properties.

Comment: for me , it's . textView.enabled = NO;

Answer (score 22):

You can use the property `editable`

```
textView.editable = NO;
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to Objective-C... Where do I put that?

Comment: So if you want it to not be editable when your view is loaded put textView1.editable = NO; in the loadTextView1 method

Answer (score 6):

### Swift 2.0 Version

```
self.textView.editable = false
```

More details can be found in the apple [UIKit Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/).

---

**Additional UITextView Attributes to consider:**

- text
- attributedText
- font
- textColor
- editable
- allowsEditingTextAttributes
- dataDetectorTypes
- textAlignment
- typingAttributes
- linkTextAttributes
- textContainerInset

Answer (score 6):

**For Swift 3.0 and Swift 4.0:**

```
textView.isEditable = false
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this one's certainly being done to death! Sorry to add another but I should mention you can remove any user uncertainty with:

```
commentTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using interface builder, you can just uncheck "Editable" in the Attributes Inspector.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Answer (score 1):

cell.txtViewAllGyms.isEditable = false

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

```
func loadTextView1()
 {
    let textView1 = UITextView()
    textView1.text = "Example of non-editable UITextView"
    textView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textView1.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 29, width: 290, height: 288)
    textView1.isEditable = false
    addSubView(textView1)
}
```

Otherwise in Xcode's Interface Builder uncheck "Editable" in the Attributes Inspector for the text view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent all user interaction you need to do the 2 following things:

```
    self.commentText.isEditable = false
    self.commentText.isSelectable = false
```