# If we click on the AddCommentsButton the AddCommentsTextView must enable. how to implement in swift iOS?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, swift5

```
@IBOutlet weak var AddCommentsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var AddCommentsTextView: UITextView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.AddCommentsButton.setTitle("Add Comments", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    self.AddCommentsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControl.State.normal)
    AddCommentsTextView.rchDelegate = self as? RCHTextViewDelegate
    AddCommentsTextView.delegate = self as? UITextViewDelegate
    AddCommentsTextView.placeholder = "Leave a comment"
    AddCommentsTextView.canShowBorder = true
    AddCommentsTextView.addBorderWithCornerRadius(cornerRadius: 0, borderColor: .Gray, borderWidth: 0.5)
    AddCommentsTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.AddCommentsTextView.font = UIFont.dynamicFont(control: .listKeyText)
    self.AddCommentsTextView.textColor = UIColor.listKeyTextColor()
}

@IBAction func didTapAddCommentsButton(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Comment: You want to enable/disable a UITextView?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067853/uitextview-how-to-really-disable-editing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITextView: How to really disable editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067853/uitextview-how-to-really-disable-editing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for when you click on **didTapAddCommentsButton** button then the **AddCommentsTextView**  Textview should show the cursor in the textview for entering the text then you can use:

```
@IBAction func didTapAddCommentsButton(_ sender: Any) {
       self.AddCommentsTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

So that on button click it will enable textview cursor for entering purpose.

UPDATED:

If you want to remove focus from the text entry then use:

```
self.AddCommentsTextView.resignFirstResponder()
```

Comment: previously the text view must be disable. if we click on the button then only the textview must be enable.

Comment: Please check updated answer. It may help you.
Textfield will enable only when button clicked else you can put disable code where you want to disable text entry..
What issue now your facing in this?